# Оптимизация JS кода табов

Tags: javascript, html, css, оптимизация

JavaScript начал учить недавно, хотелось бы узнать можно ли сократить запись табов JS чтоб выглядело более оптимизировано.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.conditions-control__item').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '')

    document.querySelectorAll('.conditions-control__item').forEach(
      (child) => child.classList.remove('conditions-control__item_active')
    );

    document.querySelectorAll('.conditions-content__item').forEach(
      (child) => child.classList.remove('conditions-content__item_active')
    );

    item.classList.add('conditions-control__item_active');

    document.getElementById(id).classList.add('conditions-content__item_active');
  });
});

document.querySelector('.conditions-control__item').click();
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.conditions-control__item { display: inline-block; padding: 0.5em 2em; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom-width: 0; }
.conditions-control__item_active { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="conditions-wrap">
  <div class="conditions-control">
    <a href="#tab-1" class="conditions-control__item">tab_1</a>
    <a href="#tab-2" class="conditions-control__item">tab_2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="conditions-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="conditions-content__item">hello tab-1</div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="conditions-content__item">hello tab-2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что значит "оптимизированно"? У  вас браузер зависает?

Comment: имел ввиду сокращенно*

Comment: Табы можно вообще делать на чистом css

Comment: да вроде как они кривовато будут работать разве нет? а так более по феншую

Comment: в одном цикле `document.querySelectorAll('.conditions-control__item').forEach`  можно сделать сразу два remove. как минимум

Comment: Для начала, стоит убрать создание N функций (по числу элементов) в forEach, предварительно объявив обработчик. И убрать две вложенные выборки, переиспользуя одну выборку перед внешним циклом. И вместо `remove` и `add` с тем же классом, применять один `toggle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.conditions-control__item'),
      tabsContent = document.querySelectorAll('.conditions-content__item');
const tabHandler = evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const id = evt.target.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
  for (const tab of tabs)
    tab.classList.toggle('conditions-control__item_active', tab === evt.target);
  for (const content of tabsContent)
    content.classList.toggle('conditions-content__item_active', content.id === id);
};
for (const tab of tabs)
  tab.addEventListener('click', tabHandler);
tabs[0].click();
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.conditions-control__item { display: inline-block; padding: 0.5em 2em; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom-width: 0; }
.conditions-control__item_active { color: red; }
.conditions-content__item:not(.conditions-content__item_active) { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="conditions-wrap">
  <div class="conditions-control">
    <a href="#tab-1" class="conditions-control__item">tab_1</a>
    <a href="#tab-2" class="conditions-control__item">tab_2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="conditions-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="conditions-content__item">hello tab-1</div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="conditions-content__item">hello tab-2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Изменения:

- один общий обработчик клика по вкладке
- переиспользование выборок из DOM (вкладки, элементы контента) выполняемых однократно
- замена `forEach` на `for..of` (имхо, так код более читаемый)
- использование метода `classList.toggle` вместо комбинации `classList.remove` + `classList.add`

---

Вместо цикла по всем элементам вкладок, можно просто снимать класс `conditions-control__item_active` у элемента текущей вкладки, а затем добавлять этот класс элементу той вкладки по которой кликнули.

То есть, заменив

```
for (const tab of tabs)
    tab.classList.toggle('conditions-control__item_active', tab === evt.target);
```

например на выборку `querySelector`'ом:

```
document.querySelector('.conditions-control__item_active').classList.remove('conditions-control__item_active');
evt.target.classList.add('conditions-control__item_active');
```

Альтернативами выборке одного элемента с "активным" классом может быть живая коллекция (исп. `document.getElementsByClassName`) или запоминание текущей вкладки в переменной.

При замене цикла на две операции, переменная `tabs` станет не нужна: клик по первой вкладке после инициализации можно выполнить выбрав ее вызовом `document.querySelector('.conditions-control__item')`, т.к. результатом вернется первый элемент вкладки в документе.

Все же, я считаю что такие оптимизации здесь будут уже чересчур: циклы не добавят заметных тормозов, при этом они проще и нагляднее.
Выборки при каждом клике тоже не очень сильно затормозят, но они заодно и снижают читаемость - а контекст вопроса (как следует из уточнений) понимает под "оптимизацией" улучшение в балансе между скоростью и лаконичностью кода.

Если все же хочется больше оптимизаций именно в производительности, то вот (без циклов + делегирование обработки событий на захвате):

```js
const CL_TAB = 'conditions-control__item',
      CL_CONTENT = 'conditions-content__item',
      CL_TAB_ACTIVE = CL_TAB + '_active',
      CL_CONTENT_ACTIVE = CL_CONTENT + '_active',
      tabsContent = [...document.querySelectorAll('.' + CL_CONTENT)];
let curTab = null,
    curContent = tabsContent[0];
document.querySelector('.conditions-control')
  .addEventListener('click', tabHandler, true);
document.querySelector('.' + CL_TAB).click();

function tabHandler(evt) {
  if (!evt.target.classList.contains(CL_TAB)) return;
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (evt.target === curTab) return;
  curTab?.classList.remove(CL_TAB_ACTIVE);
  (curTab = evt.target).classList.add(CL_TAB_ACTIVE);
  curContent.classList.remove(CL_CONTENT_ACTIVE);
  const id = evt.target.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
  (curContent = tabsContent.find(content => content.id === id))
    .classList.add(CL_CONTENT_ACTIVE);
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.conditions-control__item { display: inline-block; padding: 0.5em 2em; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom-width: 0; }
.conditions-control__item_active { color: red; }
.conditions-content__item:not(.conditions-content__item_active) { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="conditions-wrap">
  <div class="conditions-control">
    <a href="#tab-1" class="conditions-control__item">tab_1</a>
    <a href="#tab-2" class="conditions-control__item">tab_2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="conditions-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="conditions-content__item">hello tab-1</div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="conditions-content__item">hello tab-2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129471/discussion-on-answer-by-yar85--js--).